# Randomly assign sample into groups in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a big dataset consisting of some demographic information for each individual from different cities. I want to create a variable (e.g. class) which assigns individuals of same age group within a city into groups of around 20 (~ 15-25) people.
Here is an R code to generate an example of my data:

```
    set.seed(10)
    ID = seq(1:10000)
    df <- as.data.frame(ID)
    df$City <- cut(runif(10000, 0,100),breaks = c(0,7,20,35,47,55,61,74,85,91,100),include.lowest = T,right = F, labels = c("City 1","City 2","City 3","City 4","City 5","City 6","City 7","City 8","City 9","City 10"))
    df$Age_Group <- cut(runif(10000, 0,100),breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,101),include.lowest = T,right = F, labels = c("0-9","10-19","20-29","30-39","40-49","50-59","60-69","70-79","80-89","90+"))
    table(df$Age_Group,df$City)
```

I want `df$class` to group individuals of similar age group and city. Values of class need to continue after for all age groups and cities. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `toString`.

```
df$class <- factor(apply(df[c("City", "Age_Group")], 1, toString))
levels(df$class)
# [1] "City 1, 0-9"    "City 1, 10-19"  "City 1, 20-29"  "City 1, 30-39" 
# [5] "City 1, 40-49"  "City 1, 50-59"  "City 1, 60-69"  "City 1, 70-79" 
# [9] "City 1, 80-89"  "City 1, 90+"    "City 10, 0-9"   "City 10, 10-19"
# [13] "City 10, 20-29" [...]
```

To get random samples, you could split the data set `by` `"class"` into subsets, say `s`, and calculate how many groups you get, when you divide the `nrow(s)/20` (individuals) by 20. Use `ceiling` of this probably decimal point number, say `x`, and exploit then recycling properties of R; bind `1:ceiling(x)` to `s` using `cbind` and let it recycle to `nrow(s)`, where we may safely `suppressWarnings`. Of course we want now use `sample` to disturb the order, and just want column `[,2]`. Finally use `do.call(rbind(.))` to unsplit the data set, and delete the `rownames` if we want.

```
set.seed(1)  ## for sake of reproducibility
df <- `rownames<-`(do.call(rbind, by(df, df$class, function(s) 
  transform(s, SAMP=suppressWarnings(
    sample(cbind(s$class, SAMP=1:ceiling(nrow(s)/20))[,2])
    )))), NULL)
```

*Result:*

Yields `"SAMP"` column with approximately equal sized groups with ~20 members for each `"class"`.

```
df[60:70, ]  ##example rows
#      ID    City Age_Group          class SAMP
# 60 8766 City 01       0-9   City 01, 0-9    4
# 61 8775 City 01       0-9   City 01, 0-9    1
# 62 9021 City 01       0-9   City 01, 0-9    3
# 63 9041 City 01       0-9   City 01, 0-9    3
# 64 9482 City 01       0-9   City 01, 0-9    1
# 65 9622 City 01       0-9   City 01, 0-9    1
# 66   47 City 01     10-19 City 01, 10-19    4
# 67  698 City 01     10-19 City 01, 10-19    3
# 68  833 City 01     10-19 City 01, 10-19    1
# 69 1166 City 01     10-19 City 01, 10-19    1
# 70 1221 City 01     10-19 City 01, 10-19    2
```

*Check first ten tables of the classes with its SAMPles:*

```
by(df$SAMP, df$class, table)[1:10]
# $`City 01, 0-9`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 17 16 16 16 
# 
# $`City 01, 10-19`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 18 17 17 17 
# 
# $`City 01, 20-29`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 18 18 17 17 
# 
# $`City 01, 30-39`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 19 19 19 19 
# 
# $`City 01, 40-49`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 19 19 19 18 
# 
# $`City 01, 50-59`
# 
# 1  2  3  4  5 
# 18 17 17 17 17 
# 
# $`City 01, 60-69`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 16 16 16 16 
# 
# $`City 01, 70-79`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 19 19 19 19 
# 
# $`City 01, 80-89`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 20 19 19 19 
# 
# $`City 01, 90+`
# 
# 1  2  3  4 
# 18 17 17 17
```

Case you want the numbering by class rather than altogether, just `paste` `"class"` (as numeric) and `"SAMP"` together.

```
df <- transform(df, SAMP2=paste(as.numeric(class), SAMP, sep="."))
head(df)
#    ID    City Age_Group        class SAMP SAMP2
# 1 193 City 01       0-9 City 01, 0-9    3   1.3
# 2 480 City 01       0-9 City 01, 0-9    1   1.1
# 3 742 City 01       0-9 City 01, 0-9    2   1.2
# 4 757 City 01       0-9 City 01, 0-9    1   1.1
# 5 811 City 01       0-9 City 01, 0-9    3   1.3
# 6 870 City 01       0-9 City 01, 0-9    3   1.3
```

Comment: Thanks jay.sf for your reply.
This code groups everyone from same city and age group together. What if I want to randomly assign members of each level in groups of 20 (~ 15-25)?

Comment: Thank you! The code works fine and it solved my problem. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The `caret` package can help you with this.  It will attempt to create n partitions while respecting categories like `Age` and `City` given the unbalanced nature of the input it won't be perfect.  But you can chose the number of partitions (a.k.a. folds) and see what suits your needs,  I went for 5.

```r
require(caret)
#> Loading required package: caret
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
set.seed(10)
ID = seq(1:10000)
df <- as.data.frame(ID)
df$City <- cut(runif(10000, 0,100),breaks = c(0,7,20,35,47,55,61,74,85,91,100),include.lowest = T,right = F, labels = c("City 1","City 2","City 3","City 4","City 5","City 6","City 7","City 8","City 9","City 10"))
df$Age_Group <- cut(runif(10000, 0,100),breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,101),include.lowest = T,right = F, labels = c("0-9","10-19","20-29","30-39","40-49","50-59","60-69","70-79","80-89","90+"))
# table(df$Age_Group, df$City)
df$class <- caret::createFolds(df$Age_Group,
                               5,
                               FALSE)
table(df$class, df$City, df$Age_Group)
#> , ,  = 0-9
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     18     27     28     29     15      8     22     21      9      21
#>   2     16     29     31     27      9     10     19     23     12      22
#>   3     12     20     26     26     20     11     30     22     12      18
#>   4      9     27     24     28     13     12     24     31     12      17
#>   5     10     22     36     31     13     13     23     24     11      15
#> 
#> , ,  = 10-19
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     13     22     13     22     11      9     38     18     22      23
#>   2     12     23     34     21     13      7     26     22     16      16
#>   3     14     25     30     25     13      7     30     23     11      12
#>   4     13     29     31     19     22     17     23     16      9      11
#>   5     17     22     24     23     18     20     22     15      9      20
#> 
#> , ,  = 20-29
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     14     28     31     24     12     10     35     22     12      14
#>   2      9     32     22     29     15      9     30     19     18      19
#>   3     18     35     25     17     14     13     22     18     19      21
#>   4     15     26     33     25     11     15     37     20      1      19
#>   5     14     20     31     32     12     14     23     16     18      21
#> 
#> , ,  = 30-39
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     13     28     29     22     24     14     24     19     18      21
#>   2     15     28     31     32     19     14     21     25     16      12
#>   3     17     30     28     22     20      9     22     29     14      21
#>   4     18     26     33     23     10     16     23     24     13      26
#>   5     13     26     40     24     12      8     25     21     20      23
#> 
#> , ,  = 40-49
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     16     26     41     16     19     13     19     18     16      22
#>   2     18     23     36     32      8     12     28     15     16      18
#>   3     19     27     29     23     11     16     33     13     15      21
#>   4     13     21     30     29     18     18     26     19      9      23
#>   5      9     34     27     27     17      9     27     22     11      23
#> 
#> , ,  = 50-59
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     21     28     28     21     15     10     25     26     21       8
#>   2     12     17     24     25     20     20     25     32     14      13
#>   3     19     27     35     30     10      8     19     24     13      17
#>   4     19     23     30     23     19     11     19     25     16      18
#>   5     15     37     38     18     10     15     23     25      9      13
#> 
#> , ,  = 60-69
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     12     29     31     25     14     15     12     27     11      20
#>   2     12     22     29     25     18     14     22     20     11      24
#>   3     11     27     30     21     15     16     22     23     15      16
#>   4     17     21     32     20     12     12     24     28     11      19
#>   5     12     27     37     31     11     11     17     16     17      18
#> 
#> , ,  = 70-79
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     10     23     27     36     13      7     29     20     13      17
#>   2     25     19     27     27     18      8     25     17     10      20
#>   3     12     17     27     26     13      5     34     24     14      23
#>   4     12     28     34     22     15      8     28     21     14      13
#>   5     17     30     40     23     13     11     21     17      7      16
#> 
#> , ,  = 80-89
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     10     27     26     34     17     16     23     19      8      16
#>   2     17     19     33     16     19     19     16     31     12      14
#>   3     14     24     27     23     14     10     25     23     12      23
#>   4     12     25     30     33     14     16     19     14     12      20
#>   5     24     24     25     26     20      6     18     20     13      20
#> 
#> , ,  = 90+
#> 
#>    
#>     City 1 City 2 City 3 City 4 City 5 City 6 City 7 City 8 City 9 City 10
#>   1     16     21     30     25     20     15     31     23     10      11
#>   2     15     25     34     28     16     13     25     19     10      17
#>   3     12     23     30     26     19     14     24     23     13      18
#>   4     13     30     30     24     15     10     23     25     14      18
#>   5     13     16     24     24     23     17     30     23     18      15
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>